# Image is off by a few pixels on different monitor sizes, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I've looked all over and can not find a direct answer how on how it should be done. The website is  http://f9k.net/ and as you can see on different monitors the 42 logo in the middle of the page towards the left gets displaced by a few pixels. How do I stop that. I plan on adding a few more images as well.

Here's my code.

```
<body>

<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; width: 100%;" SRC="topBar.png">

<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:220px; LEFT:350px;" SRC="numberBox.png">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:700px; LEFT:0px; width: 100%;" SRC="bottomBar.png">

</body>
```

Comment: So you want the 42 with the white around it to be in the middle?

Comment: No I want it to be in between the very left of the page and the top 42 logo. So 1/4 of the way in the page horizontally. It shows up like that on my laptop but on my desktop it shows up closer to the middle. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Use `left:25%` and `margin-left:-176px` and it will always be there. Also please do not use inline CSS. Use a stylesheet, it makes everyone's lives easier including yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because its position is fixed at left:350px it remain in left 350px make it like this

```
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:220px; LEFT:25%; margin-left: px;" SRC="numberBox.png">
```

margin left should be negative half of your image size